# Submit button is not hitting Action Method from partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have populated a datatable using partial view which also contains a form, but this form submit button is not working, not hitting the controller.

This is my parent view==>:

```
<table class="table table-bordered mydatatable table-responsive-md table-hover" style="width:100%">

    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>From Account</th>
            <th>Cheque Number</th>
            <th>Cheque Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Clearing Date</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="bg-white">
        @foreach (var item in Model.TransactionModels)
        {
            <partial name="UnClearedPayments" model="item" />
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a partial view==>:

```
@model Society.Excel.Model.TransactionModel

<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" asp-controller="Clearance" asp-action="UpdatePayment" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.FromAccountName
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="TransactionPaymentReferenceRid" />
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="TransactionRid" />
        </td>
        <td>@Model.ChequeNumber</td>
        <td>@Model.ChequeDate?.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td>
        <td>@Model.Amount.ToString("0")</td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" asp-for="ClearingDate" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Update</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

This is an action method to be hit by the submit button==>:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdatePayment(TransactionModel model)
        {
            transactionViewModel.TransactionModels = _transactionLogic.GetAllPaymentClearing(UserSessionState.ApplicationUser.SocietyRid);

            if (Validate(model))
            {
                model.UpdatedBy = UserSessionState.ApplicationUser.UserName;
                if (_transactionLogic.UpdatePaymentClearing(model))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorViewModel.PleaseTryAfterSomeTime);
                    return View("Index", transactionViewModel);
                }
            }
            return View("Index", transactionViewModel);
        }
```

This is TransactionModel==>:

```
 public class TransactionModel
    {

        public TransactionModel()
        {
           // TransactionRid = Guid.NewGuid(); // TODO: Check in update use case
            SelectedInvoices = new List<Guid>();
            TransactionInvoices = new List<TransactionInvoice>();
        }

        public Guid TransactionRid { get; set; }
        public Guid TransactionPaymentReferenceRid { get; set; }
        public Guid TransactionInvoiceRid { get; set; }
        public Guid SocietyRid { get; set; }
        public Guid FromAccountRid { get; set; }
        public Guid ToAccountRid { get; set; }


        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public string PaymentTypeName { get; set; }
        public string FromAccountName { get; set; }
        public string ToAccountName { get; set; }
        public string ChequeNumber { get; set; }
        public string Narration { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }


        public int BookRid { get; set; }
        public int BankRid { get; set; }
        public int PaymentTypeRid { get; set; }
        public int BookTransactionNumber { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal OutstandingAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal AdjustedAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal BalanceAmount { get; set; }



        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ChequeDate { get; set; } = null;
        public DateTime? ClearingDate { get; set; } = null;
        public DateTime? AccountableDate { get; set; } = null;
        public DateTime CreatedByDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedByDateTime { get; set; }

        public IList<Guid> SelectedInvoices { get; set; }
        public IList<TransactionInvoice> TransactionInvoices { get; set; }


    }
```

It doesn't showing any error. just not working.

Comment: Can you add the model structure

Comment: Ok, I'm adding now, but the problem is form is not hitting the action Method.